# Proving the artihmetic property of a theory

Tags: first-order-logic, peano-axioms

When can we say a threorom is arithmetic?
Is it by following the first 9 axioms of Peano arithmetics?
Or should it only allow us to express idioms of natural numbers?

For example, can we add a claim stating there exists a real number (e.g. 1.5) to the rest of Peano's axioms and it will remain arithmetic?

Answer (score 1):

If we are considering first-order languages, *arithmetic* is a collection of *languages*.

We can the symbols $0$ and $S$ and, in addition, some or all of : $<, +, \times$.

With them, we can formulate several theoris, according to the set of axioms adopted :

> [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) : $\mathsf {PA}$
>
> [Robinson arithemetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) : $\mathsf {Q}$
>
> [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic).

With this kind of f-o languages we can try to express the axiom :

> there exists a real number (e.g. $1.5$)

with something like : $\exists z \ [z \times S(S(0)) = S(S(S(0)))]$ or $\exists z \ [z + z = S(S(S(0)))]$.

Of course, adding it to the nine Peano axioms we get a new theory $\mathsf {PA}_{1.5}$ whose model (if any) will be no more $\mathbb N$.

Comment: So can the unified set of PA axioms and the one I suggested (that there exists a real number) still be considered arithmetic?

Comment: @DoronZarhi - if with [Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic) we mean - as in primary education - the basic operations with natural numbers, integers, fractions, and decimals (using the decimal place-value system), the answer is : yes.

Comment: Okay, so lets assume now my claim is that there exists a number that is divisable by 0. Will it remain an arithmethic theory?
If not, then it means I can add claims to PA axioms that will negate the arithmetic property, correct?

Comment: @DoronZarhi - you cannot add an axiom saying $\exists z \exists w (z \ne 0 \land w \times 0=z)$ because $z=w \times 0=0$ by 1st axiom for mult : contradiction !